# Make outlook add a signature based on a certain value

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

So in outlook you can select an email address in the from field for a new e-mail. I was wandering, can I make outlook add a signature based on the value in the From field. So when i send on behalf of a certain email address i want to have a specific signature added automatically.

I would just like to know if it is possible before i spent any time trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to setup signatures for different email accounts.

1. Open a new email message.
2. Select **Signature > Signatures** from the **Message** menu.

[image: Select Signature from the Message menu]
[image: Select Signature with a reply or forward in the reading pane]

3. Under the **Choose Default signature**, choose the email account you wish to setup the signature blocks for.
4. Under **Select signature to edit**, choose New, and in the New Signature dialog box, type a name for the signature.
5. Under **Edit signature**, compose your signature.

[image: Type a new signature to use in your email]

**Note**: if you want to create a more fancy style of signature, use Word to format your text, then copy and paste the signature into the Edit signature box.

Depending on your Outlook version the menu items may be in different spots, refer to the below.

- [Outlook 2013-2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2)
- [Outlook 2007-2010](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2#ID0EAACAAA=2010,_2007)